# Нейронные сети без настройки весов

Tags: алгоритм, нейронные-сети

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существуют ли такие нейронные сети, которые обучаются без учителя и для которых не требуется предварительная настройка весовых коэффициентов.

Comment: А как же они тогда обучаться будут?

Comment: В современной науке нет чёткого понимания как естественная нейронная сеть работает. И при этом Вы хотите работающую искусственную нейронную сеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая разновидность нейронных сетей как самоорганизующиеся карты. Они могут подойти под ваше описание. [Нейронные сети: обучение без учителя](http://www.fidel-kastro.ru/programming/ii/N3.htm). Вообще в качестве общего метода обучения, практически не требующего начальной подстройки, могут использоваться разнообразные генетические алгоритмы.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще два вида - Autoencoder и RBM(Restricted Boltzmann Machine), построенные на их основе накапливающие автоассоциативные сети (stacked autoassociators network.